# CakePHP NestedList set li class

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How Can i set class for specyfic li in NestedList in CakePHP?

My code:

```
$this->Html->nestedList($data, array(), array('class' => 'active'));
```

This code add `class active` but to all li elements. I want add example to first or second li only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/
and use the Tree Helper to output your data.
The callbacks or elements can dynamically decide via passed data what to mark "active".

Comment: Ok thanks Mark, than is it best way to create example horizontal menu with set active page?

Comment: Not sure if it's the best way. Depends on your requirments. You could also code sth yourself pretty quick. But the more complicated a nested list becomes, the better to use a more generic and DRY approach.